# Exporting multiple csv files from an object in R

Tags: r

I've 10 excel files that I need to read them first, then I want to export each one of them as .csv file.  I use the following code to read them all:

```
mydir = setwd("~/Dropbox/AnalysisFolder")
myfiles = list.files(path=mydir, pattern="*.xlsx", full.names=TRUE)
myfiles
```

After reading the 10 excel file they're stored into one object in the environment, how can I write each one of them to .csv file, with keeping the name of the new .csv file as it is in the excel file?
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take help of `lapply`, read the excel file with `read_excel`. Change `xlsx` extension to `csv` and write the file with `write.csv`.

```
setwd("~/Dropbox/AnalysisFolder")
myfiles = list.files(path=mydir, pattern="*.xlsx", full.names=TRUE)

lapply(myfiles, function(x) {
  data <- data.frame(readxl::read_excel(x))
  write.csv(data, sub('xlsx$', 'csv', basename(x)), row.names = FALSE)
})
```